# svg.node.getScreenCTM() is unavailable in Firefox

Tags: firefox, d3.js, svg, interop

Here is my code and the code of the full version(not minified) of the `d3.js v5.4.0` which produces the error:

```
const onMouseMoveSvg = function() {
      const currentMouse = d3.mouse(svg.node()); //this line produces an error
      ...
};


function mouse(node) {
  var event = sourceEvent();
  if (event.changedTouches) event = event.changedTouches[0];
  return point(node, event); //this line produces an error
}

function point(node, event) {
  var svg = node.ownerSVGElement || node;

  if (svg.createSVGPoint) {
    var point = svg.createSVGPoint();
    point.x = event.clientX, point.y = event.clientY;
    point = point.matrixTransform(node.getScreenCTM().inverse()); //this line produces an error
    return [point.x, point.y];
  }

  var rect = node.getBoundingClientRect();
  return [event.clientX - rect.left - node.clientLeft, event.clientY - rect.top - node.clientTop];
}
```

The code works fine in Chrome and Opera. So, I just checked what is different there. And the thing that is different is the result of `node.getScreenCTM()`. In Chrome and Opera I am getting an object, while in Firefox it tells me that the result of the function is unavailable.

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

While searching for the solution of the problem on my own I found [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=905122). And it is said over there that the issue is tackled and should not be encountered any more:

> svg-edit is fixed now so perhaps we can mark this invalid (again).

But here we are and I am still having the issue. I am using `Firefox Quantum 61.0.1 (64-bit)`.

So, does anyone know the solution to the problem?

It is not that easy to put up the example, because the problem appears in a relatively big project. But here are the steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Go to over [here](https://resourceful-bear-239353-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/FirefoxBugFirefoxBugRepresenterRepresenter).
2. Provide the following login info:

> **username**: yrslvtrfmv@resourceful-bear-239353.com
>
> **password**: qwerty123456

3. You will be presented with the page which has a yellow rectangle with a text on it:

[image]

[image]

4. Now, move the mouse over the rectangle. In Chrome and Opera there will be no problems, but in Firefox you will get an error. And the error will be due to the result of `getScreenCTM()` being *(unavailable)*.

Here I will attach the code parts which prove that the problem behind it lies in the result of `getScreenCTM()` being *(unavailable)*:

[image]
[image]

Comment: var svg = node.ownerSVGElement || node; looks wrong but you'd need to provide a [mcve] really.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I updated the question.